# Create a "Lasershow" in form of video for a beamer

Tags: video

A "Lasershow" can be simulated with a video for a beamer - and of course a hazer, which floods the room with fog.

Example: https://vimeo.com/83762431

If you don't like to watch the video, I explain, what type of video should be created.

- points which move on the projection area
- lines …
- polygons …
- whatever combinations of those three
- in different colours

The software used in the video calls [Beamerlasershow](http://www.beamerlasershow.com/de/) and looks interesting but it is only for iOS.

I'm looking for one for macOS (or Windows, which I have on a virtual machine).

There's free software [Musicbeam](http://www.musicbeam.org/) which is OK, but not as powerful as "Beamerlasershow", mentioned above.

Can you recommend other software for that purpose?

It can be free or commercial software.

I would love to have a software, which offers sliders to create the effects "live" on the fly. And ideally, which is able to react (optional) to beats/sounds.

Comment: Please detail exactly what you mean by "not as powerful". List of all the features you need.

Comment: Beamerlasershow offers much more patterns for example:

http://static2.iphonecake.com/appcake/appimg2/1406/785430951-ipad-0.jpg

http://static2.iphonecake.com/appcake/appimg2/1406/785430951-ipad-1.jpg

Comment: Please do not force us to click on links. Instead, explain using text and screenshots if needed. Please include this information in the body of your question, as comments get deleted. Thanks!

Comment: Well I respect your wish and will add the information, but please, I disagree in that case with you. The topic is "how to create a specific type of video". The best way to explain that are not words or pictures but a video.

Comment: You totally have the right to not only disagree, but also create a new post at https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com so that the community can discuss the pros/cons and decide of a policy regarding this case and similar future cases. Cheers! :-)